# Google Spreadsheets - Selected cells increase all by X

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Spreadsheet with prices. I want to select all cells and increase the value by 30.

I did a long research on Google but couldn’t find a correct fix for this problem.

**This is my Google Spreadsheet**
[Google Spreadsheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GoZ6.png)

**Some details but not necessarily important**
Horizontal is the width and vertical is the height of the product. And all the numbers are the prices.

I have this Spreadsheet with the corrects prices. But I need to make a couple more Spreadsheets with product variants. The product variants will have the base prices but I need to increase all the prices by X amount. For example the first variant I need to increase all prices by 30.

**What did I try?**
I tried to write the number 30 in a empty cell and copy it. Then I selected all cells and tried conditional paste, but that did not work as expected. It did not increase all cells by 30 but changed all values to 30.

I also tried some other "fixes" found on the internet but did not work either.

**Screenshot for a fix in Microsoft Excel**
Here I fixed it in Microsoft Excel with conditional pasting. First you copy the number 30 and then you select all cells. After that you right click and choose conditional pasting. And then you add 30 to all cells. Weird that this isn't possible in Google Spreadsheets
[Screenshot for a fix in Microsoft Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35sRx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an empty space like A50, paste the formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B2:X30 +30)
```

The formula adds 30 to the entire range and outputs it. You can simply copy "paste values only"  over the original range.

Comment: Perfect, this was exactly what I needed. Simple & effective. Thank you Master!

Answer (score 0):

Add a value to every selected cell

```
function myfunk(v=30) {//using default parameter
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
 const rgl = breakUpRangeList1(ss,sh,sh.getActiveRangeList());
 rgl.getRanges().forEach(r => r.setValue(r.getValue() + v))
}
```

The following function breaks up all of the ranges into separate single cell ranges.  This is done because the normal getRangelist function collects adjacent cells into multicell arrays.

```
function breakUpRangeList1(ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0"), rgl) {
  let b = [];
  rgl.getRanges().forEach(rg => {
    rg.getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
      let row = rg.getRow() + i;
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        let col = rg.getColumn() + j;
        b.push(sh.getRange(row, col).getA1Notation())
      })
    })
  })
  b = [...new Set(b)];
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(b));
  return sh.getRangeList(b);
}
```

Here's a version with a prompt:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let r = ui.prompt("Enter Value", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
  if (r.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    let v = Number(r.getResponseText());
    const rgl = breakUpRangeList1(ss, sh, sh.getActiveRangeList());
    rgl.getRanges().forEach(r => r.setValue(r.getValue() + v))
  }
}
```

The following version posts all of the modifications into the minimum two dimensional array that encompasses all of your selected cells and fills in the data that needs to be changed into the array and sets them all at one time with setValues().  So it performs the modifications much faster.  But if there are formulas within that range they could be modified inappropriately.

```
function myfunk1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let r = ui.prompt("Enter Value", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
  if (r.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    let v = Number(r.getResponseText());
    const rgl = breakUpRangeList1(ss, sh, sh.getActiveRangeList());
    var ob = rgl.getRanges().reduce((a, r, i) => {
      let a1 = r.getA1Notation().toLowerCase();
      let row = r.getRow();
      let col = r.getColumn();
      if (i == 0) {
        a.rowStart = row;
        a.rowEnd = row;
        a.columnStart = col;
        a.columnEnd = col;
      } else {
        a.rowStart = (a.rowStart < row) ? a.rowStart : row;
        a.rowEnd = (a.rowEnd > row) ? a.rowEnd : row;
        a.columnStart = (a.columnStart < col) ? a.columnStart : col;
        a.columnEnd = (a.columnEnd > col) ? a.columnEnd : col;
      }
      a.ranges.push(a1);
      return a;
    }, { rowStart: 0, columnStart: 0, rowEnd: 0, columnEnd: 0, ranges: [], getA1: function () { return sh.getRange(this.rowStart, this.columnStart, this.rowEnd - this.rowStart + 1, this.columnEnd - this.columnStart + 1).getA1Notation() } });
    var o = sh.getRange(ob.getA1()).getValues().map((r, i) => {
      return r.map((c, j) => {
        let idx = ob.ranges.indexOf(sh.getRange(i + ob.rowStart, j + ob.columnStart).getA1Notation().toLowerCase());
        return (~idx) ? c + v : c;
      });
    });
  }
  sh.getRange(ob.getA1()).setValues(o);
}
```

Comment: How do I add a function, or which one of these do I have to paste somewhere?

Is there no easier solution just like selecting all cells and then do something like function add x? Or is there no easier way?

Comment: Take your pick which one do you wish to use?  The second one is a helper function for the other three.

Comment: For example I just made it work in Microsoft Excel with conditional pasting. Is this not possible in Google spreadsheets?

*Image added in post*

Comment: From your question I get the feeling that you don't program much.  So it sounds like you probably may want to used the one that prompts you for the added value which could be negative

Comment: Yes I did not understand alot of it. That's why I tried to google my question in Excel. And found a solution there. Do you know why or if that solution is possible within Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: The version with a prompt allows you to select all of the cells and then run the function and it prompts you for the value and they it adds that value to whatever value is already there.  I am not familiar with the dialog in your image and I don't read German